# What are helpers in Symfony and how do we create them?

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm starting with Symfony 1.4 and i'm having some problems understanding helpers and knowing where and how i can create them. Are they just functions? Can i create queries inside them?

Comment: Treasure here http://www.google.co.in/search?q=What+are+helpers+in+Symfony+and+how+do+we+create+them%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: Differente topic, but you know that Symfony2.0 was just released, right? If you are about to start a new project, you might consider using the latest version. (Just saying).

Answer (score 2):

Helpers are some functions that should be used in templates, and which goals are to format data. They shouldn't run queries, only transform existing data, because they are part of the View (as in MVC).

Create a helper if you execute the same transformation of an existing data many times. (Ex: format a date, etc.)

Comment: I have created a TestHelper.php inside /apps/myapp/lib/helper, but strangely, i'm getting a "Call to undefined function hello_world()". I tried using the "use_helper" function, as well adding to the standard_helpers directive to the settings.yml. What can be wrong?

Comment: You should place the TestHelper.php in /lib/helper/TestHelper.php not inside the apps folder.